# PermanentRedirect error while uploading to S3 bucket with aws-sdk-java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a file from a java class to aws S3.

I am using the exact code  as given   [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html)

The only parts I changed are these:

```
private static String bucketName     = "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<my-bubket-name>";
private static String keyName        = "*** Provide key ***";
private static String uploadFileName = "/home/...<localpath>.../test123";
```

I am not sure what to add in *Provide Key* . But even if I leave it this way, i get an error like this :

> Error Message:    The bucket is in this region: null.Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: *******)
>   HTTP Status Code: 301
>   AWS Error Code:   PermanentRedirect
>   Error Type:       Client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<my-bucket-name>` you should put `<my-bucket-name>`.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have used the correct region.
Changing the region from `us-west-2` to `us-east-1` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the name of your bucket. KeyName is the place inside your specified bucket where you wanna store your file. It should something like this:

```
private static String bucketName = "xyz";// xyz is my bucket name at s3
private static String keyName = "upload/test/";// this is location where 
//file will be stored
private static String uploadFileName = "/home/...<localpath>.../test123";
```